# TBB on low (default) security settings won't open any webpages even with JS enabled?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, javascript

I'm using the latest Tor browser bundle on low default security settings, and nothing will open. One out of every fifty pages will open. I tried enabling Javascript too, and it still won't open anything. I used to have better functionality with the security settings on high, than I am now setting them to low. I don't see a point in even using this browser anymore. I can't turn the security any lower; why is it blocking EVERYTHING?

Comment: Are these clearweb pages or hidden services (onion sites)?

Comment: Could you give some examples for non-working sites? I have the slider usually on one of the two highest settings and nearly all sites work.